# Are there characters in which the radicals are the same but the position changes the meaning?

Tags: traditional-characters, simplified-characters, radicals

Are there any characters in Chinese that have the same radicals in their formation, but the position of those radicals result in different meanings.

e.g. A character made up of two radicals, AB, and another BA, that is also a valid character.

Traditional or Simplified is fine.

Comment: I wrote an article about this last year. Some of the content overlaps with the answers already given here: http://www.hackingchinese.com/chinese-characters-components-different-meanings/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Same meaning:**

崕 = 崖 (ㄧㄚˊ / yá) = cliff; precipice

峰 = 峯 (ㄈㄥ / fēng) = peak; summit

毗 = 毘 (ㄆㄧˊ / pí) = to adjoin; to border on

群 = 羣 (ㄑㄩㄣˊ / qún) = group; crowd

飃 = 飄 (ㄆㄧㄠ / piāo) = to float

鄰 = 隣 (ㄌㄧㄣˊ / lín) = neighbor; adjacent

**Different meanings:**

早 (ㄗㄠˇ / zǎo) = early; morning
旪 (ㄒㄧㄝˊ / xié) = 協 = agreement

吟 (ㄧㄣˊ / yín) = to chant; to recite
含 (ㄏㄢˊ / hán) = to contain; to keep in mouth

旱 (ㄏㄢˋ / hàn) = drought; dry
旰 (ㄍㄢˋ / gàn) = 傍晚 = sunset; dusk

岳 (ㄩㄝˋ/ yuè) = mountain; peak
岴 (ㄑㄩ/ qū) = 嶇 = rugged; rough

星 (ㄒㄧㄥ / xīng) = star
甠 (ㄑㄧㄥˊ / qíng) = 晴 = clear (weather)

啻 (ㄔˋ / chì) = only
啼 (ㄊㄧˊ / tí) = cry; crow

There are many many others.

Comment: I'm actually going to mark this one as the accepted answer because I want to use the "same meaning" ones for the thing I'm working on.

Answer (score 3):

if you're looking for "difference positions of radicals / components" with the same meaning, here're some more:

[慚 (u+615a)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%85%9A), 慙 (u+6159)

[幕 (u+5e55)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B9%95), 幙 (u+5e59)

[炮 (u+70ae)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%82%AE), 炰 (u+70b0)

in modern usage, the first character would be considered as "the correct" one, while the second character is variant (異體字).

**but**, in literatures of yore, it's the opposite. that, 慙, 幙 & 炰 are used more.

edited, 4 more samples:

[裡 (u+88e1)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%A3%A1), [裏 (u+88cf)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%A3%8F)

[稿 (u+7a3f)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%A8%BF), 稾 (u+7a3e)

[慼 (u+617c)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%85%BC), 慽 (u+617d)

[屻 (u+5c7b)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B1%BB), 岃 (u+5c83)

have fun :)

Comment: 谢谢你 ...........

Comment: u re welcome :) do u ve enough samples for yr works now?

Comment: Yeah! Between all the answers I'm all set :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept A = B:

林

if A != B:

杏 呆

部 陪

Comment: Aren't the radicals in your third example actually two different ones?